# How to read value from a html image back to django view function?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I generate lots of images in html from local folders. I want to add links to all of these images (And triggered by a view function create_pc) and I want to send the image path to my view function.

This is a part of my html file

```
{% load static %}

<h1>Color images:</h1>
<ul>
{% for img_path in Color %}

    <li><a href="/create_pc/"><img src="{% static img_path %}" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In urls.py I have set the address to the function:

```
path(r'create_pc/',views.create_pc)
```

My function in view.py:

```
def create_pc(request):
    return HttpResponse(str(img_path))
```

So I want to get the src="{% static img_path %}" in the create_pc function, which means the function knows which image is clicked.
I don't know how to handle this. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it in your view, you need to put it in the URL. For example:

```
{% static img_path as static_path %}
<a href="/create_pc/?img_path={{ static_path }}"><img src="{{ static_path }}" ...></a>
```

Now in the view you can get `request.GET['img_path']`.